# In Junit4, How to change @Before behavior based on @Test annotations

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I would like my @Before method to know the currently executing tests Annotations, so that the @Before method can do various things. Specifically, right now our @Before always does various initialization steps like reloading the database, etc. I would like to be able to write code like this:

```
@Before
void setUp() {
    if (testMethod.hasAnnotation(@NeedsDatabase)) {
        reloadDatabase();
    }
}
```

I guess one solution would be to use a @Rule for DB initialization, but this would be complicated to implement and our existing infrastructure already handles this in @setUp. We already have a custom Runner and all tests extend a shared base class, if that helps.

I tried to think of a way to do this, but I don't know what is available in JUnit4.

Comment: There are ways to do this which mimic your need and do not unnecessarily add too much indirection to the code.  I would keep it simple : in any test which "needs a database", simply call a special  setupDB method.  This will make the tests independent of any external framework that runs them.  In general, the DRY strategies for unit testing don't add too much value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [@RunWith](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotion, and create your own [ParentRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.html) that scans for your @NeedsDatabase annotation and handles setup appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Use @Rule with TestWatcher and implement starting()

http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html#starting%28org.junit.runner.Description%29

Comment: does starting() get executed before or after @Before? I can't really move the behavior out of @Before right now, but if I could grab the Annotation[] list in starting() and store it in a class-local member variable, that would work.